# Inno Setup: shared files are not being deleted from my install directory

Tags: inno-setup

I have created an installer using Inno 5.5.9 and am installing a number of binary files that need to be marked as shared because a second installer could install a second program to the same directory and these files are common across the two programs.

I am marking the files with the flags 'sharedfile uninsnosharedfileprompt' but they are not removed on uninstall even if they are not in use.

In my testing I install the main program and then uninstall it immediately. The uninstall log says it is 'decrementing shared count' for these files but the shared count is not reaching zero. This is a 32bit program installed onto Windows 10.

```
#define SourceDirectory "..\bin2017\win32" 
#define InstallPath "{app}\bin\Win32\"

[Files]
Source: "{#SourceDirectory}\*.dll"; DestDir: "{#InstallPath}"; Flags: ignoreversion sharedfile uninsnosharedfileprompt
```

What am I missing to make this work correctly? What could be preventing the uninstaller from decrementing the shared count to zero?

If you need any more info or code please let me know (this is my first question on the excellent site). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post installer and uninstaller log files from a fresh machine that never had those files/your application installed before.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl While waiting for a VM to setup to get the logs I re-installed the program on my PC but to a location on Program File (x86) which is not the default. When I uninstalled the program the files were all deleted correctly. Installing to the default location the files are still not deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to figure out how or why it has that orphan reference.

Answer (score 1):

The path in the original location has most likely some orphan reference.

I believe your code is correct and the installer behaves correctly. It's just a local problem with reference counting.